# PHP memcached add function failing

Tags: php, memcached

I am running PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu. Memcache and Memcached are installed but the basic test I have tried (below) is not having the expected result.

```
$m = new Memcached();
$ok = $m->addServer('localhost', 11211, 20);
print("SERVER ADDED $ok<br />");
print_r($m->getServerList());
print("<br />Add: ".$m->add('foo', "hi", 600)."<br />");
print("CODE: ".$m->getResultCode()."<br />");
var_dump($m->get('foo'));
```

This is outputting

```
SERVER ADDED 1
Array ( [0] => Array ( [host] => localhost [port] => 11211 [weight] => 20 ) ) 
Add: 
CODE: 26
bool(false)
```

basically the add function does not appear to be caching the data. I've been stuck on this for a few days now and just wasted a weekend trying to work it out, so any help gratefully received!

Comment: A resultCode of 26 is an add error. If an entry with that key already exists on the server, then it will return this error. What does $m->getResultMessage() give you? Why not use the set() method instead of add()?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, have already tried set() with same result. $m->getResultMessage() gives 'SYSTEM ERROR' for both.